# Subclassed UIView from NIB File not typed to subclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, nib

I have a NIB file, with some class (SomeClassView : UIView) set as the custom class of the top level view of the NIB. SomeClass has IBOutlets that I use to hookup subviews of SomeClass that I lay out in Interface Builder.

I instantiate SomeClass like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SomeClassView" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0] retain]; 
    // "SomeClassView" is also the name of the nib
    if (self != nil) {
        self.frame = frame;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now say I subclass SomeClass with SubClassView. I add a method to SubClassView called -(void)foo:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self != nil) {
        [self foo];
    }
    return self;
}
```

At this point I get a runtime error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SomeClassView foo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xAAAAAA'

It seems as though "self" within initWithFrame of SubClassView is still set to the super, SomeClassView. A quick hack fix to work around this is to change the isa pointer within SubClassView initWithFrame:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    Class prevClass = [self class];
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self != nil) {
        isa = prevClass;
        [self foo]; // works now
    }
 }
```

It's not an ideal workaround, since I have to update isa each time I subclass, or there could even be different init methods which I'll also have to update.

1) Ideally, is there an easy way to fix this, purely by code? Maybe with the way I'm setting self = the loaded nib?

2) Is there an alternative architecture that works better for what I'm trying to do? One example is to set the owner to self, but then you'd have to set all the property/outlet mappings manually.

Answer (score 3):

Swapping isa pointers is a problem if your subclasses have instance variables other than those declared in `SomeClassView`. Note that your nib file has an object of type `SomeClassView`, which means that, upon loading the nib file, the nib loader will allocate an object of that type and unmarshall it from the nib file. Changing the isa pointer to `[SubViewClass class]` temporarily won’t make it an object of type `SubViewClass` per se since what the nib loader allocates is a `SomeClassView` object.

That said, I don’t think there’s a reliable and automatic way to use nib files containing objects whose types need to be changed upon nib loading.

What you could do is to have your `SomeClassView` objects declare a delegate conforming to some protocol. This protocol would define methods for behaviour in `SomeClassView` that can potentially be extended. For instance,

```
@protocol SomeClassViewDelegate
@optional
- (void)someClassViewDidAwakeFromNib:(SomeClassView *)someClassView;
@end
```

Instead of subclassing `SomeClassView`, you’d have arbitrary objects performing whatever custom behaviour you currently have in `SubClassView`. For instance,

```
@interface SubClassViewBehaviour : NSObject <SomeClassViewDelegate>
…
@end

@implementation SubClassViewBehaviour
- (void)someClassViewDidAwakeFromNib:(SomeClassView *)someClassView {
    // whatever behaviour is currently in -[SubClassView foo]
}
@end
```

A `SubClassViewBehaviour` object would be created in code and set as the nib file’s owner upon loading the nib file, or any other IB proxy object for that matter. `SomeClassView` would have a delegate outlet connected to file’s owner/proxy object, and it’d invoke the delegate methods in the appropriate places. For instance,

```
@implementation SomeClassView
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    SEL didAwakeFromNib = @selector(someClassViewDidAwakeFromNib:);
    if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:didAwakeFromNib]) {
        [[self delegate] performSelector:didAwakeFromNib withObject:self];
    }
}
@end
```

One further remark: your code currently leaks a view object since two objects are being instantiated: one via `+alloc` in your code and another one via nib loading. You’re assigning the latter to `self`, hence the one created via `+alloc` is leaking. Also, I believe you’ve missed a call to `super` in your third code snippet.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the 3rd snippet. I think I accept the fact that it doesn't make sense to be changing a nibs type by subclassing.

Comment: @roblocop It would be useful, though. I think it warrants filing an enhancement request radar.

Comment: @Bavarious, do you still recommend this implementation or is there a better one now that we are in 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than do this from within the subclass itself why not ensure it is the right class when you first instantiate it from outside the class:

```
SubClass *instance = [[SubClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeClassView" bundle:nil];
```