# How to subClass a view which created from an Xib file

Tags: ios, storyboard, subclass, xib

I have a viewA is loaded from Xib.
My question is that how to subClass this viewA.

Every time when the my SubClass inited, and call `[super init]`, it will return `[viewA class]`.

Similar situation happened in Storyboard, when I want to subClass a viewController which loaded from Storyboard.

Comment: do simple subclass and then in storyboard builder select view you want "subclass" and change its type by: select identity inspector (view on the right, third icon) and in `class` text field type desired class name.

Comment: @MarekR this will change the original View. Actually I want both the original View and the sub view can all load from the original Storyboard, and I will add some special logic for the subClass one.

Comment: JerryZhou, welcome to our community of devs which are waiting for XIB subclass feature ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564729/subclassing-a-uiview-subclass-loaded-from-a-nib , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547649/subclassed-uiview-from-nib-file-not-typed-to-subclass, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334007/subclassing-a-custom-collection-view-cell-created-from-a-nib ...

Comment: @brigadir  thanks.  Sad to just wait.